# removing parts of method of superclass

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, dialog

i am currently learning about inheritence and overriding methods. I was able to add to a certain method but now i am struggling to remove something from a method of the superclass. More specifically my superclass is the Dialog class from simpledialog of tkinter. I want to change the buttonbox() method in my Subclass so that the cancel button is hidden or removed. I will show the '**init**' method and the buttonbox method of the Dialog Superclass:

```
class Dialog(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent, title = None):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.withdraw() 
        if parent.winfo_viewable():
            self.transient(parent)
        if title:
            self.title(title)
        self.parent = parent
        self.result = None
        body = Frame(self)
        self.initial_focus = self.body(body)
        body.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        self.buttonbox()
        if not self.initial_focus:
            self.initial_focus = self
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.cancel)
        if self.parent is not None:
            self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (parent.winfo_rootx()+50,
                                  parent.winfo_rooty()+50))
        self.deiconify() # become visible now
        self.initial_focus.focus_set()
        self.wait_visibility()
        self.grab_set()
        self.wait_window(self)

    def buttonbox(self):
        box = Frame(self)
        w = Button(box, text="OK", width=10, command=self.ok, default=ACTIVE)
        w.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        w = Button(box, text="Cancel", width=10, command=self.cancel)
        w.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bind("<Return>", self.ok)
        self.bind("<Escape>", self.cancel)
        box.pack()
```

So now when creating my Subclass i want to inherit the Superclass but override the buttonbox method so that i only have one Button (the Button with the OK).

```
MyDialogClass(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def buttonbox(self):
        #code that will override the buttonbox method of superclass
```

How do i override this ?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, i tried around and i think i got a solution, i feel a bit stupid now.

```
MyDialogClass(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def buttonbox(self):
        box = tkinter.Frame(self)
        w = tkinter.Button(box, text="OK", width=10, command=self.ok, default="active")
        w.pack(side="left", padx=5, pady=5)
        self.bind("<Return>", self.ok)
        box.pack()
```

My main problem in the beginning was, that i got a NameError when using "box = Frame(self)" like the Superclass buttonbox method did. Now that i used tkinter.Frame(self) it worked.